# Porque quando eu coloco o text-decoration: none; dentro da ul {} apenas ele não retira o underline dos links

Tags: html, css, front-end, menu, navegação

Porque quando eu coloco o **text-decoration: none;** dentro da **ul {}** apenas ele não retira o underline dos links a dentro das li do ul? E ai eu tenho que fazer um **ul a {}** para que isso aconteça?

```css
/* CSS--------- */

#menu-lateral {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

ul{
    list-style-type: none;
}

ul a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilo.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <nav id="menu-lateral">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">Inicio</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Doces</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Salgados</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Bolos</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Porque no estilo CSS do user-agent (estilo padrão que vem do navegador para qualquer página web) o text-decoration está aplicado diretamente a todos elementos `<a>` da página, se você aplicar none no UL, ele só vai retirar do UL, mas como UL não tem tal estilo então não funciona.

Veja na imagem que mostra o devtools do Firefox com a opção Estilos do navegador (user-agent style) habilitado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

As propriedades text-decoration-color, text-decoration-line, text-decoration-skip-ink, text-decoration-style e text-decoration-thickness estão aplicadas diretamente a qualquer elemento `<a>` da página e em nenhum lugar é usado a propriedade inherit do CSS, logo não tem como A herdar de UL quando você aplica.

Então a solução de fato é usar `ul a`, como você fez:

```
ul a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

De qualquer forma ao invés de aplicar globalmente, como você fez, o ideal seria aplicar somente ao MENU, ficando assim:

```
#menu-lateral {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#menu-lateral ul{
    list-style-type: none;
}

#menu-lateral ul a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Dessa forma evitará conflitar com estilos de outros ULs e As da sua página.

Comment: Muito obrigado @Guilherme Nascimento me elucidou muito, ainda estou pegando essas questões de herança.